# react material-ui how can I set a horizontal distance between the fields?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

how can I set a horizontal distance between the fields in material UI?

Does somebody has any idea?

I have prepared a demo with the code in [codesendbox](https://e3207.csb.app/).

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Grid](https://material-ui.com/components/grid/#grid) component.

You can easily organize them inside the Grid and it will respect all spaces and other rules you define.

example:

```
<Grid container spacing={2}>
 <Grid item>
  <Input />
 </Grid>
 <Grid item>
  <Input />
 </Grid>
 <Grid item>
  <Input />
 </Grid>
</Grid>
```

I modified your code sandbox and added it to the proper place, so you can check a [**Live example here!**](https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-visvesvaraya-xhlnf?file=/src/App.js) or [**here for full page app**](https://xhlnf.csb.app/)

Comment: 1000 thanks, it works.
Why didn't it not work in the Grid_Line style.
Do you have any idea?